# Why does EF convert DateTime.Now to SQL Server time rather than EF time?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I have an Azure SQL Server database running in UTC timezone, and a C# EF WebApi running in the EST timezone.

Changing either the SQL Server timezone or WebApi's timezone is not an option.

In this query EF is using the SQL Server's DateTime.Now value:

```
var results = db.Table1.Where(t => t.PublishedDate < DateTime.Now)
```

In this query EF is using the WebApi value for DateTime.Now:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var results = db.Table1.Where(t => t.PublishedDate < now)
```

The second query returns the correct results based on the WebApi's timezone.

Why does EF interpret DateTime.Now as the SQL Server's timezone in the first example? Is there a way to prevent that so the first query works correctly?

Comment: The first example will pass the expression using DateTime.Now to SQL server to translate into SysDateTime(). The second example is just passing a DateTime variable so EF will pass the date literal to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF has a translation for understanding what the `DateTime.Now` property is, so it will translate that to SQL. With SQL Server that will translate to `SysDateTime()` which will result in SQL Server using server local time.

If you capture DateTime.Now to a DateTime variable then EF will treat that is no different than any other date literal, so you can pass an application server local datetime, or UTC etc.

Note that if you try something like:

```
var results = db.Table1.Where(t => t.PublishedDate < DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
```

or

```
var results = db.Table1.Where(t => t.PublishedDate < DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());
```

to force local vs. universal time EF (6) will throw an exception because these methods on DateTime.Now cannot be translated to SQL. EF Core may accommodate these methods by executing the SQL minus this expression, then applying the expression in memory afterwards, so some care should be taken with EF Core or performance issues may catch you out.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to prevent EF from converting DateTime.Now to SysDateTime()?

Comment: Yes.  Simply declare a local variable and assign it to the time, and use that in your query.